# Which version of ARM does the M1 chip run on?

Tags: assembly, arm

Recently, I've been trying to learn ARM assembly (ARM because my Mac can run it), but all the tutorials and recources that I can find all have slightly different variations, and the version that I have working is different again!

Some of the versions I've seen have `.section .text` and `.section .data`, and other websites have a bunch of `svc` calls (or whatever they're called) that are completly different for what I have. I haven't found any places that have code that works with me (except [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0OXp0zqIo0), but I already know how to do everything in it)

Here's my hello world program that runs on my laptop:

```
// Print 'Hello, world!" to stdout"

.global _main
.p2align 3 // no bus error idk

_main:
    // Print 'Hello, world!'
    mov x0, #1      // Use file stdout
    mov x16, #4     // Write to stdout
    adr x1, message // Address of message to print
    mov x2, #13     // Length of message
    svc 0           // Execute

    // Exit
    mov x0, #0      // Move return code to register 0
    mov x16, #1     // Service command code 1 terminates this program
    svc 0           // Call service call 0 (exit program)

message:    .ascii  "Hello, world!"
```

Input to terminal:

```
user@laptop folder % make src=helloWorld 
as   -o helloWorld.o helloWorld.s
ld -o helloWorld helloWorld.o
make clean
rm *.o
user@laptop folder % ./helloWorld
Hello, world!%
```

In summary, I need some sources that can teach me how to write assembly for my M1 Mac (2020 touchbar)

Comment: Get a tutorial that is specifically for macOS.   Anything else won't do it.  Lots of details differ between operating systems and macOS is especially different in that it uses Mach-O instead of ELF.  A Linux tutorial will not help you.